# Passing cookies to Image.GetInstance

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-3.0, itext

Using image handler to convert relative path to absolute.

```
    protected byte[] ConvertHTMLToPDF(string HTMLCode)
    {
        if (Request.Url == null)
            throw new Exception();

        var doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
        doc.Open();

        var interfaceProps = new Hashtable();
        var ih = new ImageHander {BaseUri = Request.Url.ToString()};

        interfaceProps.Add("img_provider", ih);

        foreach (IElement element in HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(HTMLCode), null, interfaceProps))
        {
            doc.Add(element);
        }

        var _xmlr = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(HTMLCode));
        HtmlParser.Parse(doc, _xmlr);

        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, stream);

        doc.Close();
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
```

class:

```
public class ImageHander : IImageProvider
{
    public string BaseUri;

    public Image GetImage(string src, Hashtable h, ChainedProperties cprops, IDocListener doc)
    {
        string imgPath;

        if (src.ToLower().Contains("http://") == false)
            imgPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority + src;
        else
            imgPath = src;

        return Image.GetInstance(imgPath);
    }
}
```

imgPath at the end is correct. But it's not static file, it's url of action that returns image, so I need to pass cookies when requesting image. Is it possible?

Comment: What's `Image.GetInstance`?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I've posted more details

Comment: Still nothing about what `Image.GetInstance` is and what it does. Apparently it sends an HTTP request to the remote endpoint to retrieve the image. This is where you should include the cookie. Or if this GetInstance method doesn't allow you to send cookies along with the request you could manually send the HTTP request to retrieve the image Stream from the remote endpoint and then create the image from this stream.

Comment: `Image.GetInstance` is a method of itextsharp library and yes, it sends request to get image. shall I include cookie values in src of image? like this: `<img src="./src?sessionId=value" />`

Comment: Oh no, cookies are sent as HTTP headers: `Cookie: CookieName=CookieValue`.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov then I'll make custom method myself which will act like Image.GetInstance, but i'll include headers too. Thanks Darin

Comment: Yes, that's what you need to do. I have posted an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but you're gonna have to send the request yourself and not rely on the `Image.GetInstance` method. For example using the [`HttpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) you could send cookies along with the request:

```
var imageUrl = new Uri(imagePath);
var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler { CookieContainer = cookieContainer })
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
{
    cookieContainer.Add(
        new Uri(imageUrl.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)), 
        new Cookie("CookieName", "cookie_value")
    );
    var response = client.GetAsync(imageUrl).Result;
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    Stream imageStream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;

    // You've got the Stream here, read the documentation of iTextSharp 
    // how to create an Image instance from a Stream:
    return Image.FromStream(imageStream); // ?????

    // or maybe there's a method allowing you to create an Image from byte[]
    byte[] imageData = new byte[imageStream.Length];
    imageStream.Read(imageData, 0, imageData.Length);
    return Image.FromByteArray(imageData); // ?????
}
```